# Delete List selectedItem from the array?

Tags: c#, arrays, listbox

I have a text file that is read on the program startup and it populates a simple array. The array is then used to populate a listBox. Now what I want to do is to let the user select a item in the listBox and delete it. When the item is deleted the array should update accordingly and the listBox should be populated with the new array again(I have a function for that).

Here's what I use to populate Array:

```
string[] cArray = new string[10];
int counter, count;
public void loadArray()
{
    try
    {
        StreamReader inputfile = File.OpenText("Classes.txt");

        classList.Items.Clear();
        while (!inputfile.EndOfStream)
        {
            cArray[count] = inputfile.ReadLine();
            count++;
        }
        inputfile.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Message, "Loading Error!");
    }
}
```

And this is custom function I made to display the data into the listBox whenever I make any updates.

```
public void displayClasses()
{
    try
    {
        classList.Items.Clear();
        for (counter = 0; counter < count; counter++)
        {
            classList.Items.Add(cArray[counter]);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Message, "Displaying Error!");
    }
}
```

I tried this using Nirupam's reply:

```
private void deleteButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        while (classList.SelectedItems.Count != 0)
        {
            classList.Items.RemoveAt(classList.SelectedIndex);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }

    DeleteClasses(classList.SelectedIndex);
}

public void DeleteClasses(int indexId)
{
    cArray = cArray.Where((source, index) => index != indexId).ToArray();
    displayClasses();
}
```

The class does get deleted but with the displayClasses() it comes back, meaning it isn't being deleted from the array.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're actually asking of us. Could you clarify?

Comment: There is data in array that is loaded into a Listbox.
I want to allow user to select an item from the listbox and delete it.
Now when it is deleted it should update the array.

Comment: A nice trick I find for posting questions that are clear is to include a statement *with a question mark,* and try and make that question as specific as possible. It sounds like you're asking two things: How can I allow a user to delete an item from a `ListBox` control, and capture the deleted item's index? And how can I remove an item from an array, given that index? Is that a good summary of what you'd like us to answer?

Comment: And on top of that, are you familiar with how to do either of those, such that we don't *have* to answer them? It's alright if not, I just want to make sure we're on the same page.

Comment: Thank you for clarification, I'm aware of how to delete a item from a listBox using for loop however I was wondering if there is a way to delete the item and the data for that item from the array at the same time.

Comment: And yes, what you pointed out is exactly what I wanted to do. However I don't want the array to mess up. So for example if the index 2 is deleted from the array index 3 should now become index 2. Hope I didn't confuse you more :/

Comment: For sure, we both want to get you the best answer possible! You've lost me a bit again, though. You mention deleting via a `for` loop, which makes sense, but that doesn't seem in-line with what you said a bit ago where a user would be performing the deletion. And nope, your last comment there makes perfect sense! :)

Comment: That's because I was only able to find the for loop method to remove item from a ListBox. But I really don't care whatever method is used without a loop would be even better for me :). As I pointed as long as it updates the array accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In comments, I guessed that you were trying to ask us two separate questions:

1. How can I allow a user to delete an item from a `ListBox` control, and capture the deleted item's index?

*I'm actually not going to answer this one just yet, because we're still working out how the deletion will be performed.*

2. How can I remove an item from an array, given that index?

The best solution to this problem is to, instead of an array, use a [`List<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx). In your case, a `List<string>`.

I don't know whether you're familiar with lists, but if not, a list is like a "mutable array." You can add or remove items relatively freely. This will accomplish what you asked for in your comment, so that removing the item at index 2 would shift all subsequent items down one.

To remove an item, use the [`RemoveAt`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5cw9x18z(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
List<string> strs = new List<string>();

strs.Add("AAA");
strs.Add("BBB");
strs.Add("CCC");

strs.RemoveAt(1); // remove "BBB"

Console.WriteLine(strs[0]); // yields AAA
Console.WriteLine(strs[1]); // yields CCC
```

If you're stuck with an array for other reasons, you'd have to write the "shifting" logic yourself. I can help you with that if it's the case, but I won't bother otherwise.

For what it's worth, a list will also clean up your reading method.

---

This is probably how I would perform the remove operation in the array.

```
string[] args = new string[3];

args[0] = "AAA";
args[1] = "BBB";
args[2] = "CCC";

int indexToRemove = 1;

for (int v = indexToRemove + 1; v < args.Length; v++)
{
    if(v > 0)
    {
        args[v - 1] = args[v];
    }
}

args[args.Length - 1] = null;
```

Comment: I read this online and I too think a ListArray is better than a Array. But this is for my C# class and my teacher doesn't like when you go against the instruction -.-



The instructions are:
(4. Delete - The delete button will allow the user to delete a class from the list. The code will remove the class from the array.



Suggestion: To remove an item you will need to search for it in the array. Then you will need to shift the remaining items up one level in the array).

Comment: @SnowTauren Alright! Do you have any ideas on how to do that? I'd appreciate if you could edit your question to show what you're thinking for that, if you could. Or if you're stuck on something in particular, I can definitely help with that.

Comment: @SnowTauren I'm not sure if I'd say the LINQ solution you've provided conforms to the requirements set forth by your teacher. I edited my answer to show how I would do the removal. You'll, of course, have to change some variables around.

Comment: The index is not constant, it shouldn't remove 1 or 2. It should remove what ever the user selects from the ListBox. I don't understand how that code will work :(

Comment: @SnowTauren Do you have to support multiple deletions in a single pass?

Comment: Not necessary, only one deletion is asked.

Comment: @SnowTauren Then I'm not sure I understand your question about my code. Could you clarify?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72458/discussion-between-matthew-haugen-and-snowtauren)

Answer (score 0):

write a another function   DeleteClasses(int indexId) for better modularity of code which will return Array Data.It will be called from inside your displayClasses() methode .Inside it write down code according to Algo given below:

**Step 1 :** 
Remove the Item in cArray using parameter IndexId which we will send when we call  DeleteClasses(int indexId) method.
Code will be something like this:

```
cArray = cArray .Where((source, index) => index != indexId).ToArray();
```

return that cArray from where it will be called.

**Step 2:**
After That you will have updated Array when user choose to delete an item.
than Load your ListBox by calling displayClasses();
Note: Inside displayClasses() you should have code like this below:

```
try{
    classList.Items.Clear();
    classList.Items = cArray.ToList(); //here cArray is updated data array
   }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
   MessageBox.Show(e.Message, "Displaying Error!");
  }
```

**Overall :** 
Overall code looks something like this below:

```
Public string[] DeleteClasses(int indexId)
{
    //indexId will be depends upon user selection on demand for delete     
    // operation.
    cArray = cArray .Where((source, index) => index != indexId).ToArray();
}
public void displayClasses()
{
   try{
        int indexId=classList.SelectedItemIndex;//
        string[] cArray = DeleteClasses(int indexId);
        classList.Items.Clear();
        classList.Items = cArray.ToList(); //here cArray is updated data array
       }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
       MessageBox.Show(e.Message, "Displaying Error!");
      }
}
```

Comment: I was working with your answer and then with the updated answer you lost me again :/. Can you look at my question and see what I'm doing wrong?